# Dynamic Programming/Recursion - Understanding Rod Cutting

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

In the classic Rod cutting problem, the mathematical expression for maximum revenue is:
[image]

which can be recursively defined as:

```
maxCost(n) = max(p[n], (maxCost(n-i)+maxCost(i), for 1 <= i <= n)
```

which can be expressed as:

```
p = [1, 5, 8, 9]
def maxCost(size):
    if size <= 1:
        return size
    cost = -1
    for i in xrange(1, size+1):
        cost = max(p[i-1], (maxCost(i) + maxCost(size-i-1))) # --> stackoverflow error
        #cost = max(cost, (p[i-1]+ maxCost(size-i))) --> giving correct o/p
    return cost

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print maxCost(4)
```

The expression for the uncommented cost in the loop comes directly from the mathematical expression defined. However, this is giving SO error.

On the other hand, the expression for the commented cost is giving right answer (for n = 1, 2, 3, 4) but I'm unable to understand the derivation of this expression from the mathematical expression.

Can anyone please help/tell me what's wrong in the uncommented expression for cost and how/why the commented line is correct  ?

Comment: Yet another "here is my code, debug it please" post.  For what i do you receive the error?  What happens if you remove everything except the first line, i=(something), and the uncommented expression? What happens if, you replace the expression just by p[i-1]? etc.

Comment: To receive the error - just run it !! What else can you do ?  And if you understand recursion, there's no need to even run it !! Debugging ? NO !! But trying to understand what's actually happening underneath recursive calls

Comment: Do you know what would cause that error while using recursion?

Comment: Unable to converge on the value of size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the recursion

```
maxCost(n) = max(p[n], (maxCost(n-i)+maxCost(i), for 1 <= i <= n)
```

is correct?

Based on http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-rod-cutting.html, the recursion is

```
q = max(q, p(i) + Cut-Rod(p, n-i)
```

This matches your commented line

```
cost = max(cost, (p[i-1]+ maxCost(size-i)))
```

To answer your question on why you are seeing an SO error...

The un-commented recursion you are using

```
cost = max(p[i-1], (maxCost(i) + maxCost(size-i-1)))
```

calls `maxCost` twice: for `i` and for `size-i-1`.

This puts you in an infinite recursion even for an input of 2.
I put a couple of print statements in your code to show what happens.

```
p = [1, 5, 8, 9]
def maxCost(size):
    print("maxCost called with size= " + str(size));
    if size <= 1:
        return size
    cost = -1
    for i in xrange(1, size+1):
        print("in loop, i= " + str(i));
        raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
        cost = max(p[i-1], (maxCost(i) + maxCost(size-i-1))) # --> stackoverflow error
        #cost = max(cost, (p[i-1]+ maxCost(size-i))) --> giving correct o/p
    return cost

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = int(raw_input().strip())
    print maxCost(size)
```

And here's the output when fed a size of 2.

```
H:\code\temp>py so.py
2
maxCost called with size= 2 #initial call size=2
in loop, i= 1
Press Enter to continue...
maxCost called with size= 1
maxCost called with size= 0
in loop, i= 2
Press Enter to continue...
maxCost called with size= 2 #called again with size=2, when i=2
in loop, i= 1
Press Enter to continue...
```

You'll notice that when i = 2, we are back to calling maxCost(2), which is exactly the same as the first time we called maxCost! Hence the infinite recursion and the SO error.

The correct recursion will stop at n-1.

```
rk=max(pk,r1+rk−1,r2+rk−2,…,rk−1+r1)
```

In above equation (taken from http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-rod-cutting.html), after pk, there are exactly k-1 terms, so we have to loop from 1 to k-1 only. Hence `for i in xrange(1, size): #fixed to iterate to size-1`

Also, in your original code, when calculating cost, you need to include cost also as an input to the max() function, else you loose the cost calculated in the previous iteration. Hence, `cost = max(cost, p[size-1], (maxCost(i) + maxCost(size-i)))`

The full fixed code gives correct values for sizes 1 thru 4. 
Note: for size=4, correct output is 10, not 9.

```
p = [1, 5, 8, 9]
def maxCost(size):
    if size <= 1:
        return size
    cost = -1
    for i in xrange(1, size): #fixed to iterate to size-1
        cost = max(cost, p[size-1], (maxCost(i) + maxCost(size-i))) # --> fixed code, gives correct out of 10, for size=4
        #cost = max(cost, (p[i-1]+ maxCost(size-i))) #--> giving correct o/p
    return cost

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = int(raw_input().strip())
    print maxCost(size)
```

Comment: The recursion: maxCost(n) = max(p[n], (maxCost(n-i)+maxCost(i), for 1 <= i <= n)  seems correct. This is also given in Corman - Introduction to Algorithm: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1464070194&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+algorithms

Answer (score 1):

```
maxCost(i)
```

your function is calling itself at the same depth level, so it never gets to a base case.

```
maxCost(1) -> maxCost(1) -> maxCost(1) -> ad infinitum
```

results in the stack overflow